# How can I generate random numbers in slabs of a range in Python3 or in a specific interval of range in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, random

Suppose I want to generate 10 random numbers between 1 to 100. But I want to pick numbers randomly from each number of sets like 1-10, 11-20, 21-30,.... So that It does not come out like this: **1, 7, 26, 29, 51, 56, 59, 89, 92, 95.**
I want to pick numbers randomly like this: **7, 14, 22, 39, 45, 58, 64, 76, 87, 93**.

I have created a code sample. But I can't figure out later part of the problem.

```
import random

def getInteger(prompt):
    result = int(input(prompt))
    return result

range1 = getInteger("Please Enter Initial Range: ")
range2 = getInteger("Please Enter Ending Range: ")
range3 = getInteger("Please Enter the Range size: ")

myList = random.sample(range(range1, range2), range3)

myList.sort()

print ("Random List is here: ", myList)
```

I am new to programming. I googled about it, but did not find any solution. Thank you guys in advance...

Comment: Looks like you want to pick a random number between 1-9 ten times.

Comment: Would you elaborate? I did not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to pick 10 times a random number between 0 and 9 and add 10 in each step.

```
import random

random_numbers = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    random_number = random.randrange(10) # pick a number between 0-9
    random_number += 10*i # add 10 in each iteration
    random_numbers.append(random_number)

print(random_numbers)
```

EDIT:
if you want to set your own values, this could work:

```
import random

random_numbers = []
begin = 100
end = 200
interval = 10

for i in range(0, round((end-begin)/interval)):
    random_number = random.randrange(interval)
    random_number += round(interval)*i + begin
    random_numbers.append(random_number)

print(random_numbers)
```

Comment: Wow. Thinking outside the box. +1 much nicer then my answer for this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice) and a `for` loop:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 100, 10):              
...     print(random.choice(range(i, i + 10))) 
...                                          
10                                           
19                                           
21                                           
34                                           
45                                           
51                                           
68                                           
74                                           
88                                           
98                                           
>>> for i in range(1, 100, 10):              
...     print(random.choice(range(i, i + 10))) 
...                                          
6                                            
14                                           
30                                           
37                                           
50                                           
56                                           
65                                           
79                                           
85                                           
94
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the random.choice function.

Comment: This is not perfect. I am getting numbers like this: 10, 17, 22, 36, 50, 56, 61, 75, 81, 98. where 4_ is missing and also I am getting two times 5_ (50,56).

Comment: I just replaced '1' with '0' in the initial range of for loop in DeepSpace's answer like:      
for i in range(0, 100, 10):    and it is working fine though it can give a '0' value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
import random

start = 1
stop = 100
interval = 10

ran = [random.choice( range(start + i*interval, start + (i+1)*interval-1))
for i in range(len(range(start,stop,interval)))]
print(ran)
```

Explanation:

the `i` is selected from `0` to `len(...)` of how many intervals you would get by using `start` to `stop` with/by `interval`

For this examble it returns `10` which results in numbers for `i` from `0` to `9`.

The `random.choic`e uses this `i` to compute/chunk up the whole number-range from `start` to `stop` in chunks of `interval`s size - `choice` then draws one of the numbers in this subrange for your resulting list.

```
range(start + i*interval, start + (i+1)*interval-1)
# evaluaters to   
#    i = 0:     1+0, 1+(0+1)*10-1 = 1,10
#    i = 1:     1+10, 1+(1+1)*10-1 = 11,20
#    etc.
```

Edit: 
This might overshoot on the upper limit - which is fixable by using

```
ran = [random.choice( range(start + i*interval,min(stop, start + (i+1)*interval-1))) for i in range(len(range(start,stop,interval)))]
```

which limits the upper bound by using `min(stop, calculated end)`

Comment: I tried this code and this is also working! Thanks for your detail description... Giving it +1.

Comment: @Ryko - for your usage - dont use this its overly complicated. Use Dusans answer - but thanks for the +1